# SonarQube - File not found warning

Tags: java, sonarqube, build.gradle, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

Im using sonarqube to run sonar code analysis on my gradle java project.

The sonarqube gradle properties setup:

```
    properties {
        property("sonar.projectKey", rootProject.name)
        property("sonar.projectName", rootProject.name)
        property("sonar.host.url", "sonar_url")
        property("sonar.java.source", "11")
        property("sonar.sources", "src/main/java")
        property("sonar.tests", "src/test/groovy")
        property("sonar.analysis.mode", project.properties["sonar.analysis.mode"] as String)
        property("sonar.report.export.path", "report.json")

    }
}
```

and using `jacoco (0.8.3)` for code coverage.

Now after running the *sonarqube* task, I could see the below message.

```
> Task :sonarqube
The use of the issues mode (sonar.analysis.mode=issues) is deprecated. This mode will be dropped in the future.
Project doesn't exist on the server. All issues will be marked as 'new'.
CodeNarc completed: (p1=0; p2=0; p3=0) 551ms
Metric 'test_success_density' is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Provided value is ignored.
File not found: com/sample/project/YYYYY.java
File not found: com/sample/project/XXXXXX.java
.
.
.
.
File not found: com/sample/project/ZZZZZZ.java
```

The task is executed and the report is generated in the assigned path successfully.

But, how to get rid of these files not found warnings?

Thanks in advance.